# Problem with biased circuit for oxygen sensor (SGX EC410)

Tags: sensors, signal-processing

I have designed a circuit for an SGX EC410 oxygen sensor by using these application note -PAGE 4, FIGURE 4 - (http://www.sgxsensortech.com/content/uploads/2014/08/A1A-EC_SENSORS_AN2-Design-of-Electronics-for-EC-Sensors-V3.pdf). When I try to measure the biased voltage between working (SENS) and reference (REF) electrode, the value of -600 mV is held for about one second and goes down to few milli volts rapidly. The same happens when I connect the sensor without voltmeter. Am I doing something totally wrong, or the circuit is not quite right? 
[image]

Comment: I'd try asking at electronics.stackexchange.com instead.